# How do I include dll as reference in nuget that also gets copied as reference when nuget added to project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

We are trying to control versions of nugets being used by hosting them on our own Artifactory and not on **nuget.org** while trying to package multiple nugets into one.

Example for this is **Aspose**.

I want to create a new library called **AsposeTools** that has our own helper functions.

**AsposeTools** references: **Aspose.Cells** and **Aspose.PDF**.

When I install **AsposeTools** in my project, I want to see **AsposeTools**, **Aspose.Cells** and **Aspose.PDF** so that I can call to use both my helper functions and the actual Aspose functions.
But I want **Apose.Cells** and **Aspose.PDF** to be "installed" by **AsposeTools** not dependencies that get copied down from our artifactory or nuget.org. The reason being cause then we need to maintain version of cells and pdf in both our artifactory and what's being used in tools.

How can I tell the dependency to install from within the nuget it exists instead of a nuget source.

I've tried creating a libs folder within **AsposeTools** and added the extra dlls to that folder and added them as references. I then tried all the different options for build actions with **Copy to Output Directory** set to always. The best I could get is that, telling by file size, **AsposeTools** has the extra dlls included, but I cant actually refence them in code, only my helper functions. The **Aspose.Cells** and **Aspose.PDF** are not actually placed in the projects references

EDIT: I use .csproj currently to build the nuget

Comment: You may want to clarify if you use .nuspec of .csproj to build your nuget.

Comment: Did you want to not make `Apose.Cells` and `Aspose.PDF` as nuget dependencies for `AsposeTools` and then just references the assembly dlls in the main project?

Comment: `How can I tell the dependency to install from within the nuget it exists instead of a nuget source.` does this mean that the dependencies should not be installed as nuget package from  `nuget.org` but just references their assembly dlls directly from `AsposeTools` itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my comment's guess is right, you can just set these `Apose.Cells.dll` and `Aspose.PDF.dll` as assembly reference so that it will not install them as nuget packages from `nuget.org`.

**Note**: it will miss any dependencies of the nuget packages and if you want, you can use the same way to add them automatically.

**1)** click these nuget packages on the **Dependencies** -->**Properties** and then set their `Private Asserts` to `All`.

[image]

**Then**, right-click on the project-->**Unload project** and then click **reload Project** to enable the settings.

**2)** enter the `xxx.csproj` file of the project and then add these:

```
 <PropertyGroup>
<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
 </PropertyGroup>

 <ItemGroup>
      <None Include="$(OutputPath)Aspose.Cells.dll" Pack="true" PackagePath="lib\$(TargetFramework)"></None>
      <None Include="$(OutputPath)Aspose.PDF.dll" Pack="true" PackagePath="lib\$(TargetFramework)"></None>

 // you can add any dependency dlls of the output folder in this way as you want

 </ItemGroup>
```

**3)** repack your project and when you install the new version, you should first [clean nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) or just delete caches files under `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\.nuget\packages`.

When you install the new **AsposeTools** package, it will not install the other two packages as nuget dependencies from `nuget.org`. And they are only referenced by the main project only as **Assembly reference** and also copied into output folder.

**ConsoleApp2** is the new main project, and I have installed the new version of **AsposeTools** package into my project. And this is the effect:

[image]

Comment: This did exactly what I need. Only problem I had, was target framework. In order to have Dependencies (not references) I had to create a .net standard package, not .net framework which wont work on our 4.5.2+ application. But was a great headstart!

Comment: that <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies> is a game changer!